# Unable to retrieve data from ms access db in java

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

please take a look at this code and tell me where i've mistaken :

I just want to get the price of a service which is selected through Combobox from my ms access db
and display it in a text field

```
service_box=new JComboBox();
    service_box.setSize(20,25);
    service_box.addItem("Select a Service");
    service_box.addItem("Hair Cut");
    service_box.addItem("Facial");
    service_box.addItem("Bleaching");
```

.....

```
   service_box.addItemListener(this);
   add_bt.addActionListener(this);
```

......
....

```
 @Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent i){

     service_name=(String)i.getItem();

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ie){


    try{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc.odbc:acescon");

        String query= "Select  price from service table where service="+service_name;
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        String price_value=rs.getString("price");

        total_tf.setText(price_value);
    }
    catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e){

    }


}
```

it doesn't show any error though.

the db contains 3-columns 
1-id
2-service
3-price

Comment: I've also tried using the while loop : while(rs.next()){String price_value = rs.getString("price");}

Comment: It will show error if you do `e.printStackTrace();` in catch block or `System.out.println(e.getMessage());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SORRY FOR NOT REPLYING EARLIER .
 I WAS TRYING DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS :

I HAVE A COMBOBOX WITH SERVICES AND ANOTHER COMBOBOX WITH EMPLOYEES IN THAT AND WHEN I CLICK
ON ADD BUTTON IT SHOULD GET THE PRICE OF SELECTED VALUE FROM SERVICE TABLE FROM DB AND ADD THE NEW ROW TO THE BELOW TABLE.
SO HERE IS THE FINAL CODE I CREATED AND IT IS WORKING WELL SINCE THE NUMBER OF SERVICES ARE LESS THAN 100 IT DOESN'T CREATE ANY PERFORMANCE ISSUES,

**BUT I WOULD REALLY  APPRECIATE IF ANY ONE SUGGEST A BETTER IDEA TO DO THIS **
HERE IS THE WORKING CODE "

```
String service_name;
   String price_value = null;
    try{
       service_name=(String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem(); //GET SELECTED SERVICE
       String query= "Select * from services where service_name='"+service_name+"'";

        stmt = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

         while(rs.next())
         {
             if(rs.getString("service_name").equalsIgnoreCase(service_name)) //GET PRICE OF SERVICE
               price_value=rs.getString("Price");


         }
         //get employee name
         String emp_name=(String)jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();
           if (emp_name.equals("No one")) {
               emp_name="";
           }

           // insert the new row

      int row_count = jTable1.getRowCount();
       Object[] row_data={service_name,price_value,emp_name};
       dtm.insertRow(row_count, row_data);



    }
    catch(SQLException  e){

        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                "ERROR IN ADDING SERVICE TO BILL\n"+e.toString(),"ERROR MESSAGE",
                javax.swing.JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

    }
```

THE FOLLOWING CODE IS IN THE actionPerformed method of ADD button.

Answer (score 0):

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc.odbc:acescon");

Instead of jdbc.odbc:acescon in the above statement It should be jdbc:odbc:acescon.

By the way connection should not be created on every click of a button. Instead you can work with the same connection or connection pool to gain the performance.

Comment: oops!! i'm new to jdbc afterall. and i was jut creating the workable module for my final project so i did need that connection on that one.

Comment: I've create the connection at the starting of the class and then i'm using it in many other classes and in the above answer also please suggest me if there is a  better way to do this. i will need the connection many times in my whole application.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String query= "Select  price from service table where service="+service_name;
```

this should be

```
 String query= "Select  price from service table where service="+"'"+service_name+"'";
```

and

```
rs.next();

String price_value=rs.getString("price");
```

Comment: you code is right. i was mistaking at the name of table which should have been 'servicetable' instead of service table. But since i had some other errors i didn't got the Result